# Archbang look on Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, archbang

I installed archlinux but I want to get the look and feel of Archbang.
Is there a way to find the config files or scripts for Archbang?

http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?id=2501 gives a list of packages but I also want the resources and quick ref of key bindings in the background, menus, default application and other things I don't know about.

The reason I don't want to install Archbang is because I want to follow the Arch Way. the reason I want Archbang config files is because people already thought about usability and solved that problem for me. I like their solution.

Comment: It depends on your DE, what DE runs in Archbang?

Comment: If you figure this one out, please create an archbang package for Arch Linux that installs all the archbang configuration files (and takes backup of the old ones by using the backup=('...') directive). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Archbang wiki has a [default config page](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Default_ArchBang_Configs&oldid=3153).

Files listed include [.Xdefaults](http://ompldr.org/vYjNzNA/Xdefaults.txt), [tint2rc](http://ompldr.org/vYjNzNw/tint2rc.txt) and [conkyrc](http://ompldr.org/vYjNzNQ/conkyrc.txt), which should assist your with styling your Arch install.

Comment: Thanks, gonna check it out to make sure all configs are there and everything works.

Comment: They don't put stuff like gtk config, icon themes, gtk themes here, hmm..

Comment: I suppose the OP could just run it in a VM and copy what they need across...

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the Archbang iso, mount it and see what you find.

Comment: that is a bit time consuming. would involve figuring out what files may change and where they are. then there is always a chance if something is missing

Comment: you could download the regular iso as well, extract it and then compare the files (possibly by using version control)